# How can I force to call dynamically added element,s onclick() first

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

```
<div id="outerDiv" onclick="javascript:addEvent()">
    <div id="inner">
        <a class='editEV' href="javascript:void(0)">event1</a>//*added dynamically from addEvent method.*
    </div>
 </div>
```

My script is:

```
$('#inner').on('click','.editEV',function(){
    editEvent();
});
```

When I click on anchor `addEvent()` called first then `editEvent()`, but I want that when I click on div then addEvent() should call and when I click anchor then `editEvent`.

I am aware about bubbling so that's why I introduce an inner static div to bind listener, but still `addEvent()` calls first. I am unable to figure out how can I force to call `editEvent` first.

Comment: Use `event.stopPropogation()` in `editEvent`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#using-the-triggering-element

Comment: @Martin – IMO, it is about `propogaton`, not about `delegation`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using both - inline event set **( onclick=.. )** and Jquery **on**. Choose one of them to have more clear code. I would choose jquery **on**, and solution for this problem is to create two events - one on div, second on edit element, but in second We need to stop bubbling by using `e.stopPropagation` method. Here full working example:

```js
$(function(){

  $("#outerDiv").on("click",function(e){
  
      console.log("Add click");

  }); 
  
  $("#outerDiv").on("click",".editEV",function(e){
  
      console.log("Edit click");
      e.stopPropagation();//very important to stop propagate event

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv" style="padding:20px; background:grey;">
    <div id="inner">
        <a class='editEV' >event1</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Without `stopPropagation` our event is going up to div and runs its event, `stopPropagation` avoids propagate event to upper elements.

Comment: What is the difference between these both ""inline event set ( onclick=.. ) and Jquery on""   Does inline have higher priority?

Comment: No, priorities not exists, for sure they will be added first and run as first ( events are called in the same sequence as they are added to element ). They are the same as events in code, but code is running after DOM is ready, inline onlick adds listener ealier. I writed info about choosing one of them because code will be more understable.

Comment: so you are saying that this binding for inline listeners happens even before jquery's ready() function?

Comment: Yes that what I am saying.

Comment: @AmanNagarkoti wtf was that? My answer was set as correct 2 days ago and two minutes after primary the same answer was added You changed your mind. It is very very not fair.

Answer (score 1):

You also use this if you don't want to alter your code.

```
$(function(){

$("#outerDiv").on("click",function(e){

  addEvent();

}); 

$("#outerDiv").on("click",".editEV",function(e){

  editEvent();
  e.stopPropagation();

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

use this.
If you want to read more on .stopPropagation(), [look here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).